Slow insert using postgres foreign data wrapper
insert into my_foreign_table select * from my_local_table
My columns are two integers and two floats. The number of rows was >100M. I left it running for a few days, but killed it because it took forever.
Should this run quickly? Does Postgres do the inserts one at a time or something? Is there a way to speed inserts up via foreign data wrapper?

Maybe provide details of the machines involved and the network between them? Accompany that with timings for 100,000 rows and you stand a chance of getting a useful answer.

You can change the batch_size:
ALTER SERVER name_of_your_foreign_server OPTIONS (SET batch_size '1000');


batch_size (integer) This option specifies the number of rows
postgres_fdw should insert in each insert operation. It can be
specified for a foreign table or a foreign server. The option
specified on a table overrides an option specified for the server. The
default is 1.

